# Using mod_rewrite to return 404 for all requests on http

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-404

I am configuring apache to create a site that will use mod_jk to connect to an app running on tomcat.

I only want https requests to access my app and I would like to use mod_rewrite to return a 404 for any  http request on port 80.

Here is my attempt at a VirtualHost configuration

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName admin.app.com
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^ [L,R=404]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName admin.app.com
  SSLEngine On
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bla.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bla.key
  SSLCACertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/bla.ca
  SSLProtocol all
  SSLCipherSuite HIGHT:MEDIUM

  JkMount /myapp* 

</VirtualHost>
```

Now all is well and good when hitting https://admin.app.com/myapp - I am able to access my tomcat app confirming that mod_jk and my SSL certificates are working as I expected, however any url request I make with http:// returns 400 bad request, not the 404 that I was expecting.

I added RewriteLog and RewriteLogLevel 3 and got the following output

```
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
(3) applying pattern '^' to uri '/'
(2) rewrite '/' -> '[L,R=404]'
(2) local path result: [L,R=404]
(2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /myapp/favicon.ico/
(3) applying pattern '^' to uri '/myapp/favicon.ico/'
(2) rewrite '/myapp/favicon.ico/' -> '[L,R=404]'
(2) local path result: [L,R=404]
```

Which I interpret to mean that 404s should be returned

My question is why am I getting a 400 Bad Request when the log seems to be rewriting my requests correctly to 404s, and furthermore, what is the best practise regarding allowing a site to be accessible only via https.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't use code 404 because the problem is not that the page cannot be found, it's that the user is making a forbidden request.

Instead, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [F]
```

Then you can use a custom 403 error page to explain that only secured requests are permitted to this path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you actually answered my issue with the bad request, I had missed off the hyphen after the carat... Putting it in seems to make it work.  But I wanted to also say regarding the forbidden as opposed to the 404 that I would prefer 404 since it is a form of security by obscurity in that, unlike a 403, it hides the fact that there is any directory there at all.

Comment: I did wonder if the missing hyphen might be your problem, but I wanted to see if I could persuade you to switch to the 403 error code instead. Security by obscurity rarely lasts long, and don't forget that a 404 code might make search engines think your site contains links to dead pages, which may hurt search rankings, and could have other side effects too. Good luck, however you decide to deal with it.

Comment: @tlcowling gotta agree with you on this one, though Bobulous is right in that security by obscurity hardly lasts there's no need either to tell a potential attacker that what they're looking for exists. As long as you're sure there's no links to it, don't want to hurt SEO efforts.